# Python: Downloading Outlook Attachments and Change Filename on Save

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

the following code works below, however i am trying to add a parameter that changes the filename on the SaveAsFile method to the iteration of (a) the message that i am on.

**As an Example the Current output is**

```
Returned mail see transcript for details
Returned mail see transcript for details
```

**The Desired output is**

```
Returned mail see transcript for details1
Returned mail see transcript for details2
Returned mail see transcript for details3
```

Currently this code just overwrites the same save file in my folder, however i need to accomplish saving that same file from different messages to a new file name.

**Code Below:**

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subject = message.Subject
i = 0
#
get_path = r'S:\Corporate Shared\Contracting Shared\DATA_PROJECTS\James\Email Extraction\Undeliverable Items'

for m in messages:
    i = i + 1 #numeration
    a = str(i) #Creates i as a string
    if m.Subject == ("Returned mail: see transcript for details"):
        #print(message)
        attachments = message.Attachments
        num_attach = len([x for x in attachments])
        for x in range(1, num_attach + 1):
            attachment = attachments.Item(x)
            attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(get_path,attachment.FileName))
            print(attachment)
            #print(a)
        message = messages.GetNext()

    else:
        message = messages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `attachment.FileName` in the call to `os.path.join`, store `attachment.FileName` in a variable, then replace the last `"."` with `"_" + x + "."`